# PHP dont read seccond condition in IF, in the case of first not being true

Tags: php

I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way of writing the following;

```
if(isset($_POST['AddressLineOne'])){

    if($_POST['AddressLineOne'] != ""){

        $sAddressLineOne = $_POST['AddressLineOne'];

    }else{ 
        $sError .= "[AddressLineOne]"; 
    }

}else{ 
    $sError .= "[AddressLineOne]"; 
}
```

Could I write something similar to other languages (java?), that would prevent the seccond condtion in an `If` statement being run, if the first isnt met? i.e;

```
if(isset($_POST['AddressLineOne']) && $_POST['AddressLineOne'] != "" ){
    $sAddressLineOne = $_POST['AddressLineOne'];
}else{ 
    $sError .= "[AddressLineOne]"; 
}
```

I have written the function below, but its not always appropriate to use it, or more control is needed over the checking.

```
function CalcRequiredFields($aRequiredFields, $aPostData){

    $sError = "";
    $error = false;

    foreach($aRequiredFields as $field) {
        if (empty($aPostData[$field])) {
            $error = true;
            $sError .= "[".$field."]" ;
            $sError .= "[emptyFields]";
        }
    }
    if($error){ return $sError; }else{ return ""; }
}
```

Comment: why are you using `if(isset($_POST['AddressLineOne'])){` then doing `if($_POST['AddressLineOne'] != ""){`? you can break that down to just  `if(!empty($_POST['AddressLineOne'])){` or use a ternary.

Comment: doh! This is the anser was looking for! {walks away tail between legs}

Comment: hehehe, no problemo ;-)

Comment: so, what would you like to do here, me submit an answer or delete the question? I know some hack's gonna come around and feed off my comment lol either way is fine with me.

Comment: was just thinking the same thing, happy to accept that as an answer. But feeling quite stupid.. Is it needed, can flag for removal?

Comment: Ok, I'll put in something and with a ternary example. Give me a minute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply break down

```
if(isset($_POST['AddressLineOne'])){

    if($_POST['AddressLineOne'] != ""){
```

to just using a conditional `empty()`:

```
if(!empty($_POST['AddressLineOne'])){...}
```

or use a ternary operator:

```
$var = !empty($_POST['var']) ? $_POST['var'] : "";
```

You can also use it as an `isset()`:

```
$var = isset($_POST['var']) ? $_POST['var'] : "";
```

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Just keep in mind that `<?php var_dump( empty('0') );`  prints `bool(true)`. But given the parameter name `AddressLineOne` that's most likely not a problem here.

Comment: @VolkerK I agree. `isset()` I find is usually best against radio/checkboxes and `empty()` for text/integer inputs.

Comment: thank you! Say someone removed the input from the `dom` then submitted the form, this wouldnt be executed either way, think thats why I've been using isset. Reading the data into an array so could check it again there I guess?

Comment: @atoms Sure. My ternary example can be changed to `isset()`. I'll make an edit. Edit: done.

Comment: great one ,,,,,,,, :)